# show different images on ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

WHen I submit an ajax request for show an image:

```
$('div.loading').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('none');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $(this).addClass('none');
            });
```

However I only want to show this image for some ajax submissions not others which I want to show a different image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//set image url 
var img = images/img01.png


$('div.loading').css({'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')' }).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('none');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $(this).addClass('none');
            });
```